# Laravel Socialite Implement stateless for Twitter

Tags: php, laravel, twitter, laravel-socialite

I would like to implement stateless method to Twitter but it seems that it is not available for TwitterProvider class as it returns 
`Call to undefined method Laravel\Socialite\One\TwitterProvider::stateless()`

Here is my `redirectToProvider` method currently.

```
public function redirectToProvider($socialMedia)
{
    $provider = strtolower($socialMedia);

    return Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->redirect();

    throw new NotFoundHttpException;        
}
```

What is the correct implementation or what do I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @driesvints from this question [#415](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/issues/415) I've opened at the Laravel Socialite repository, stateless is unavailable for Twitter since it uses OAuth 1.0.

They already pushed a PR [#5661](https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/5661) to update also the Laravel Docs mentioning this specification. Click the link to see the update. [Staless Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/socialite#stateless-authentication)

I would update this answer if whatever my solution would be.